# Why is the method in __init__.py not accessible

Tags: python

I am using python 3.5.1
My directory structure is as follows

```
/app
   start.py
   /myTestPackage
      __init__.py
```

`start.py` has the following code

```
import myTestPackage
print("In start")
myTestPackage.inInit()
```

`myTestPackage/__init__.py` has the following code

```
def inInit():
    print("In the __init__ method")
```

When `start.py` is run, The following error message is displayed

```
AttributeError: module 'myTestPackage' has no attribute 'inInit'
```

In my understanding this should not have happened because when the import method is called, the `__init__.py` should have been run.

What am I missing here? Any help is very appreciated

Comment: What's the output of `print(myTestPackage.__file__)`? Does it match the location of your `myTestPackage` folder?

Comment: replicated your setup. worked for me. https://pastebin.com/EUHePdCr

Comment: can you ensure once you have the files where you said you did.